# Unable to calculate class height

Tags: javascript, html

I have been using classes on my web and now I want to calculate height of a class. It is a unique class (not being used anywhere except one).
I tried `offsetHeight` and `height` in Javascript but unable to find any output.
Suppose here is my code.

```
<div class="example">some text some text some text some text some text".</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Here is Javascript

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementsByClassName("example").offsetHeight="300px";
}
</script>
```

**Error**:
I'm not getting any output/error anywhere on the page or in the console. Hope you guys will help me and **I want only solution in Javascript not in jQuery or any other library**. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try `document.getElementsByClassName("example")[0].offsetHeight="300px";`

Comment: @Jahanzaib Asgher do you  want set or get Height?

Comment: @Alexander I wanted to get height

Comment: @Jahanzaib Asgher look at my example below, I've added variants how you can get and set height

Comment: @JahanzaibAsgher Have you seen the answerS?

Comment: Hey guys below, `gEBCN()` doesn't return an array, it returns an object ([HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns `HTMLCollection`, so you need get first element from this collection

```js
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName("example")[0];

  // get height
  var height = element.offsetHeight;
  console.log(height);

  // set height
  element.style.height = '100px';
}
```

```html
<div class="example">some text some text some text some text some text".</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the integral value on the object list index:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("example")[0].offsetHeight = 300;
```

The `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of matched elements. So you are actually applying that function on an array, which has no effect.

**Working Snippet**

```js
function myFunction() {
  alert(document.getElementsByClassName("example")[0].offsetHeight);
}
```

```html
<div class="example">some text some text some text some text some text".</div>
<button onclick="myFunction();">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The **[getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)** will return an array of objects so you have to specify wich object you want, e.g :

```
var class_height = document.getElementsByClassName("example")[0].offsetHeight;
```

To select the first object.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this.will work

```
var height = document.getElementsByClassName("example")[0].offsetHeight;    
console.log(height);
```